# Did Lee Majors do his own stunts in The Fall Guy

Tags: stunts

I am just re-watching The Fall Guy with Lee Majors. So playing a stunt man he might have done his own stunts? I searched the web and the closest thing I could find is:
[Opinion about Lee Majors](https://www.timesmojo.com/did-lee-majors-do-any-of-his-own-stunts/)

And all it says is :Who did the stunts in the fall guy? Lee Majors, And The Fall Guy Truck
(Questionable IMO)

I also read the Wikipedia site and they didn't mention anything.

So maybe someone has a better source.

Did Lee Majors do his own stunts in The Fall Guy?

Comment: There are about 50 stunt performers listed on [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081859/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_cl_sm), the first one in the list says Mickey Gilbert … stunt coordinator / stunt double: Lee Majors / stunts (35 episodes, 1981-1986) You might find something elsewhere that claims he did his own, but generally Hollywood doesn't like it, because of the dangers of losing production time if the star is injured… or worse. [Not putting this as an answer in case someone does find somthing better].

Comment: @Tetsujin. If you make this an answer I will accept it. So, Lee Majors probably did some stunts. Ok, that's good enough for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are about 50 stunt performers listed on [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081859/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_cl_sm), the first one in the list says

> Mickey Gilbert … stunt coordinator / stunt double: Lee Majors / stunts (35 episodes, 1981-1986)

You might find something elsewhere that claims he did his own, but generally Hollywood doesn't like it, because of the dangers of losing production time if the star is injured… or worse.

It's always possible a star did some of the less risky stunts, but usually only if their face would really be in shot - no CGI in those days.
Even today, most stars do not do their own stunts. Only the very rich & 'powerful' ones, who are usually also producers of the movie, so accepting some of the financial risk already. Tom Cruise & Harrison Ford spring to mind, though I think Ford is down to just a bit of horse riding these days - he is 80 after all.
Some who are also known for martial arts etc do too, but your 'just an actor' tends not to.

Comment: Jacky Chan did all his own stunts, and he DID break things now and then. I remember one movie where he uses a sword in a Ferrari to cut up the hover cushion of a hovercraft, he broke his foot and shot some of the scenes in a cast, painted to look like a running shoe.

Comment: Zoe Bell in Death Proof also springs to mind, but then she is not "just an actor".